# iOS distribute problem

Tags: ios, upload

Hi
I built apps for iPad and iPhone from one single project. I created app with all data in app store and upload iPhone binary. What I need to do for uploading iPad binary with the same name? P.S. It's not universal app.

Answer (score 1):

1) change the bundle identifier
2) use different display name for AppStore submission e.g. XX for iPad, XX for iPhone
3) but you can keep the same name below the icon

Comment: So I need to wait until iPhone app loaded?

Comment: No. You can just submit it as a new app. What's the problem ?